# Database Diagram (ERD) Final Table

Tags: sql, structure, diagram, erd

[image: Full ERD]

Is this Showroom table correct? I want to be able to see this data: 
[image: Showroom]

I'm just not sure how to reference MakeName, ModelName and Price in the showroom table, is it right as it is or do I need to change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have those fields in your ShowRoom table (unless that's just a View).  Keep that table to your Id and your CarId.  Then you can use `INNER JOINs` to return the appropriate data:

```
SELECT S.ShowRoomId, S.CarId, M.MakeName, Mo.ModelName, Mo.Price
FROM ShowRoom S
   INNER JOIN Car C ON S.CarId = C.CarId
   INNER JOIN Model Mo ON C.ModelId = Mo.ModelId
   INNER JOIN Make M ON Mo.MakeId = M.MakeId
```

Good luck.

Comment: yeah it's just a view, thanks for the reply i'll accept that answer in a minute :)

Comment: @user2058186 -- no problem, glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. If you'll inner join showroom, car, make and model you'll get the right query